# Pass data from html template to component typescript file

Tags: angular

There is a select option in the below reactive form. `post.id` will give access to the id of the individual `post.name`
So lets say the user chooses the second option from the options then `post.id` will be 2 I want to send this id when the user submits the form.

I have an alternative way of doing it where when the user submits the form then in the `contactForm.control.value` object I get the name of the option which user chose and I then search the corresponding id in the array of objects `this.posts`. I want to know if there is another way of doing this where I wont have to search.

HTML file

```
 <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="apply-form">
   <select formControlName="post">
     <option ngFor="let post of posts" value="{{post.name}}">
     {{post.name}}
     <option>
     </select>
 <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

TS file

```
     export component XXX {
     posts: any;
      ngOnInit() {
      this.posts = this.auth.getData();
    }

   onSubmit() {
 //need the post.id here
   this.auth.apiRequest(post.id, this.contactForm.value) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update the code, what are you iterating over? `<option ngFor="let ">`. Can you show us the array?

Comment: You haven't set any formControlName in your select, nor any value of ngValue on your options. What is your **actual** code?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Why do you set the value to `{{post.name}}` if you want the value to be the **id** of the post? Use [value]="post.id" if you want it as a string, or [ngValue]="post.id" if it's not a string. See https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption

Comment: I also need to send the name of the selected option as a value to the backend

Comment: Then use [ngValue]="post", and the form control's value will be the post object itself, containing both the id and the name.

Comment: `[ngValue]="post"` worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many things missing in your code, but let me give your options to get the data:

If post have only Id and Name:

```
<option ngFor="let post of posts" value="{{post}}">
```

Your button is a normal button, it's type should be submit to post the data:

```
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

If you want to send the data from page then

```
// In HTML
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.value)"
 // Add signature to your onSubmit method
 onSubmit(data){....}
```

If you want to read value in your onSubmit method then

```
onSubmit(){
   let data = this.contactForm.value;

   // To check if form is valid or not
   if(this.contactForm.invalid)
       return;
}
```

Hope it will help!